# Why was Kale Brecht under house arrest in the movie Disturbia?

Tags: plot-explanation, disturbia

In [Disturbia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486822/), why was Kale Brecht under house arrest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained right at the beginning of the [movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disturbia_%28film%29):

> A year after a devastating car accident that resulted in his father’s
>   death, teenager Kale Brecht (Shia LaBeouf) is sentenced to three
>   months house arrest after assaulting a teacher when he made a remark
>   about his father.

Comment: Then i missed something.

Comment: With that movie, you didn't miss enough. :)